# Multiplying Single Digit Numbers to Get Product >1000

Tags: game-theory

This is yet another Alice and Bob problem.

Alice and Bob are playing a game on a blackboard. Alice starts by writing the number $1$. Then, in alternating turns (starting with Bob), each player multiplies the current number by any number from $2$ to $9$ (inclusive) and writes the new number on the board. The first player to write a number larger than $1000$ wins. A sample game might be (each number is preceded by "A" or "B" to indicate who wrote it):

{A1, B3, A12, B60, A420, B1260; Bob wins.}

Which player should win, and why?

I am assuming this problem uses optimal strategy on both sides, but as there are several ways to win, I'm not sure how to prove who should win.

All I do know, is that, if the number after your operation exceeds 1000/18, but isn't greater than 1000/9, it's a guaranteed win for you.

Can someone provide me with a solution? Thanks

I also apologize for the lack of a proper tag, as I didn't know a phrase that would correctly encompass this particular scenario/game.

Comment: Anything above 1000 is a "losing number," because if you see it on the board it means you've lost. Anything from 112 to 1000 is a "winning number" because if you see it on the board you can give your opponent a losing number (i.e. you can win). Anything from 56 to 111 is a losing number, because no matter what you do you give you opponent a winning number. Etc. The question is, is 1 a winning or losing number?

Comment: (I'm assuming that the goal is to get something larger than 1000, not larger-or-equal. Not that it changes much.)

Comment: To confirm, we are allowed to reuse digits (as is suggested by the example game)?

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt Nothing in the question suggests otherwise.

Comment: @columbus8myhw I agree, I misread the problem to start with.

Comment: This is a nim game. The starting position is equal to *2 (nimber).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bob can pick between 2 and 9.
7,8 and 9 dont work as Ross Milikan pointed out as any number more than 56/9 loses.
For 4 and 6 which from bobs perspective are the winning numbers. if he picks between 4 and 6, Alice must pick between 8 and 54, so Bob can then pick between 56 and 111. Whatever Alice then picks, Bob can multiply by 9 and win, so 4, 5 and 6 are winning.
2 and 3 are not possible for Bob if Alice knows what she is doing as she can then make 4 or 6 on her next turn and use the reverse logic against Bob

Answer (score 0):

As columbus8myhw  says, $[112,1000]$ wins for the next player, so $[56,111]$ wins for the previous player, $[7,55]$ wins for the next player, $[4,6]$ wins for the previous player, so Bob should start with $4,5, \text{ or } 6$